# PrintPreviewControl with bg but don't print it out

Tags: c#, printing

All.

I would use the PrintPreviewControl to preview a document with background. But I don't want the background was printed it out.

Here's my code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        printPreviewDialog1.Document = printDocument1;
        printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        // This background should not print out, but could view in preview
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(new Bitmap(Foobar.Properties.Resources.bg), new Point());
        string text = "This text to be printed. ";
        e.Graphics.DrawString(text, new Font("Georgia", 35, FontStyle.Bold),
            Brushes.Black, 10, 10);            
    }
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this though:

```
    private bool p = true;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        printPreviewDialog1.Document = printDocument1;
        printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!p) {
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(new Bitmap(Foobar.Properties.Resources.bg), new Point());
        }
        string text = "This text to be printed. ";
        e.Graphics.DrawString(text, new Font("Georgia", 35, FontStyle.Bold),
            Brushes.Black, 10, 10);            
    }

    private void printDocument1_BeginPrint(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PrintAction == System.Drawing.Printing.PrintAction.PrintToPreview) {
            p = false;
        }
    }

    private void printDocument1_EndPrint(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e)
    {
        p = true;
    }
```